# How to zoom out screen view in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

My friend was playing one game and suddenly it crashed due to which screen resolution has been changed and now I am hardly able to work. I tried Windows logo key  + plus (+) or minus (-)  but nothing is working. What should i do to change the resolution ? Is there any shortcut which I can try ?

[image]

Comment: you mean the screen resolution of the window...or the game?

Comment: resolution to be precise

Answer (score 2):

To change your **Screen Resolution**, you can follow these simple steps:

---

1. Right-Click on the Desktop and click on **Screen Resolution**

   [image]

   **OR**

Go to:

> **Control Panel** -> **Appearance and Personalization** -> **Display** -> **Screen**
>   **Resolution**

2. Now set your resolution by clicking the drop-down list next to **Resolution**

   [image]
3. Hit **Apply** to amend the changes.